# UICollectionView reloadData - EXC_BREAKPOINT

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` in the header of my `UITableView`. I remove the collectionView if there is no data. 
I am getting EXC_BREAKPOINT crashes from line "`self.collectionView.reloadData()`"

```
var reccomend: [JSON]? = []

 func loadReccomend(){
            YazarAPI.sharedInstance.loadReccomendedArticles({ reccomend in
                if let data = reccomend["articles"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    self.reccomend = data
                    if (self.reccomend?.count)! < 1 {
                        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
                    }else{
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            })
        } 

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
                return 1
            }

            func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return self.reccomend?.count ?? 0
            }

            func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ReccomendCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReccomendedCollectionViewCell
                cell.article = self.reccomend?[indexPath.row]
                return cell
            }
```

And result of `print(data)` :

```
[{
  "title" : "title0",
  "author_email" : null,
  "author_id" : 1884,
  "read_count" : 0,
  "is_favorite" : false,

}, {
  "title" : "title1",
  "author_email" : null,
  "author_id" : 1884,
  "read_count" : 0,
  "is_favorite" : false,

}]
```

Comment: how are you returning collectionView as tableView header ?? Have you handled these cases in viewForHeaderInSection as well ???

Answer (score 0):

try using guard inside your else part:

```
 guard self.reccomend?.count > 0 else{
       return
    }
 self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to but a check there that if there is some data only then call `self.collectionView.reloadData()`. Like this :

```
if (self.reccomend.count>0)
{
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app is breaking because you are force unwrapping with: `(self.reccomend?.count)!`

The property `reccomend` here is optional, which means it is possible that 'reccomend' is nil. In your case, `reccomend` is nil because when you add the !, you are telling us you know it will never be nil and if it is the app will crash, and so it crashes.

```
if let recommended = self.reccomend {
  if recommended.count < 1 {
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
  } else {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
} else {
  //if self.reccomend is nil, do something
}
```

But that isn't the main problem here for you- your main problem is that `self.reccomend` is nil after you set it to equal `data`

You need to check what type of array `self.reccomend` is and what type of array `data` is to make sure they are the same type and that you are getting the JSON response you expect. So set breakpoints and figure that out, because that is what makes your force unwrap fail, and also why you should never force unwrap any sort of internet response.

Comment: self.reccomend and the data is the same type. I am getting JSON data from an external api. How can I to replicate the same issue?

Comment: Can you print `data` before you set `self.reccomend` equal to it? Can you also show where you declare `self.reccomend` as a property? Add both to your question above. Is `self.reccomend` declared as `var reccomend = [[String: AnyObject]]?` Or is it something else?